# change the sdktarget in android eclipse project for compatibility issues

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I have developed an android app in eclipse . the app works fine in the emulator.
I upload my apk file in google store , but when I want to install it it tells me that is incompatible with my device .

in the file androidmannifet.xml i specify this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="example.androidapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="example.Splash"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
             android:label="@string/app_name" 

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
          <activity
            android:name="example..Main">
           <!--  android:label="@string/app_name" 

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>-->
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and my device is a 2.3.3 android version. why is it incompatible?

Comment: Post all of your manifest.

Comment: What else is in your manifest? Any permissions, supported screens restrictions? The easiest way to work this out is to run your app on your device via Eclipse. When it most likely fails there too, you should have the reason shown in the console or logcat.

Comment: @hichris123 ok that is my complete file

Comment: in the eclipse emulator it works fine !

Comment: What error is it showing in google play? You might have set the filter to download only in some countries.. or any other filter settings

Comment: I meant run it on your physical phone/tablet via Eclipse which you can do by installing the necessary drivers and targetting your device instead of an AVD under the Target tab in Run Configurations. Otherwise, the only guess I can make is the external storage permission - does your device have an SD card and if so, is it mounted?

Comment: @SaneeshCS the message : this app is not compatible with your device

Comment: I've test it in my phone, my androdi version is : 2.3.3 and it's working , but i've tested it in a another androdi version : 2.3.5 and it's not working !!

Comment: anyone please ! I don't find the error in my manifest file !